# How to monitor the GridDB checkpoint log file, using Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, database-partitioning, griddb, checkpointing

I know this is a bit specific but hopefully someone has done this before.
I am using  Zabbix to monitor GradDB, and using the default provided "GridDB Monitoring Template" .

I am interested in knowing Block management information, and one of the places where its written is the  Checkpoint log file .
I do see graph for  "Checkpoint memory usage" and  " Total checkpoint and backup" like the one below:-
[image: Checkpoint elapsed time]

But is there a way to monitor the Checkpoint log file OR a graph that displays information about it ?
Thanks